# ¿Como puedo implementar una arquitectura por capas en python?

Tags: python, importación, modulos

estoy intentando hacer un programa bajo una arquitectura por capas (capa de datos, presentación y lógica de negocio) en python, pero estoy teniendo problemas al intentar importar módulos desde un directorio a otro.
Esta es mi estructura de archivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La intencion es poder utilizar un clase llamada DaoEquipos ubicada en el archivo "/AccesoDatos/dao_equipos.py" desde el archivos "/Controller/controlador.py" pero me marca error, dice que no encuentra el modulo que necesito.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named DaoEquipos

¿Python esta habilitado para hacer estas importaciones o simplemente no es posible importar un modulo de un directorio externo?. Espero su respuesta muchas gracias.

Este es el "import" desde el archivo controlador

```
from AccesoDatos.dao_equipos import DaoEquipo
```

Comment: Si no muestras el `import`, cualquier respuesta es pura especulación. Por favor, muestra el import y desde donde (dir/script.py) lo estás importando.

Comment: La pregunta es sobre `import`, no sobre arquitectura ni capas.

Comment: @CandidMoe añadi el import que utilizo al final de la pregunta. Gracias por responder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En resumen, no puedes, debes añadir las carpetas o directorios con los que estás trabajando a las variables de entorno o al PATH, puesto que el intérprete de Python primero buscará en el PATH, posteriormente buscará en la carpeta en la que reside el código ejecutado, y en ningún sitio más, esto no puede ser modificado.

Acá tienes una forma de hacerlo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: Mejor toma la pregunta (en inglés), agrega la respuesta (y comentarios), traducelos y publicalo como respuesta. Es válido si pones el link al original. Eso hará más valiosa tu respuesta y seguramente te llevaras unos puntos adicionales.